# RSpec - Large float is rounded on create

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have this strange behavior where, when I create a record with a large float number, it rounds that number.

```
MyRange.create(:a_number => 4000007100000000)
```

When retrieving the same record, I get the record with a rounded number:

```
puts MyRange.first.inspect
# MyRange(id: 1, a_number: 4000010000000000.0)

puts MyRange.inspect
# MyRange(id: integer, a_number: float)
```

Any ideas why it would do this?

Note: This happens in an RSpec test only.

Comment: Please be courteous and provide the reason for down-voting.

Comment: It rounds it, you mean by dropping the 7?

Comment: I think more of your code is required to help answer the question. If this is going via a db record, then the schema for table holding `MyRange` records is relevant. So is how your test db is built.

Comment: `create_table "my_ranges", :force => true { |t| t.float "a_number" }` I have a feeling it might have something to do with `scale` but I have not tried modified the default.

Comment: @vgoff: It appears to round to the 5th decimal place (or the 6th significant digit): `4.0000071e+15` up to `4.00001e+15`. If it were "dropping the 7", the result would be `4.000001e+15` (count the zeroes). At a guess, the degree of precision is somehow declared elsewhere in the OP's setup. Perhaps in the schema, or as the default in the test db.

Comment: @ArtemKalinchuk I think schema definition from database (rather than `db/schema.rb` file) would be more helpfull. What database are you using? Can you connect to it and check it: PostgreSQL - `\d+ tablename`, MySQL - `DESCRIBE tablename;`

Comment: @Artem Kalinchuk: How is your test db built, and is it the same system as your development db, or do you perhaps have one MySQL and one SQLite?

Comment: Development & Test are both MySQL. Here are the results from `DESCRIBE my_ranges;` on the test database: `id | int(11) | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |\n| a_number | float | YES |  | NULL |`

Comment: For reference, I build my test database with `rake db:test:prepare`

Comment: I think the default `MySQL` float precision, though not particularly high, would not produce this result. What do you see when you do `puts MyRange.all.inspect` instead of `first` (sorry if I have AR syntax wrong) - any chance you have earlier test data confusing the issue?

Comment: @NeilSlater `puts MyRange.all.inspect` gives me the same result but in an array. I doubt any previous test data is affecting the result since there really isn't any previous test data. I know this probably doesn't answer this question but I managed to change to `BIGINT` instead of `FLOAT` (since I didn't need float) and that works fine now.